# HTML 5 validation error for tables > td width when assigned as width="#%"

Tags: html, css, html-table

> ### Error Details:
>
> The width attribute on the td element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
> From line 81, column 15; to line 82, column 50:

```
<tr><td width="6%" class="texalign_right">Name:</t..
<tr><td width="6%" class="texalign_right">Details:</td></tr>
```

My current website, where i have more than 20 tables and lots of different numbers and sizes for inside td's. I believe assigning width through class for each table and then inside td will make me ill.

To AVOID this I can simply hardcode widths for tables and corresponding td (only for first row) once in table with "style" attribute.. is this make sense?

More importantly the current table # (20) may be increase to (30 or 40).

Truly I don't like hardcoding at all!! so I am very much interested if there any other way to handle table widths.

Comment: You have two choices: You can replace the `width` attribute, or you can live with the validation error. But judging from the number of tables you are using, it might be time for a rewrite anyway. [Using tables for layout is evil.](http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html) :P

Comment: If you want to do it that way, why should you care about the validator at all?

Comment: You may need to give each td a class attribute and then use CSS to style that. That's what the validator tells you. And I hope it is tabular data that you display in tables.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `<colgroup>` element of HTML 5. You can then define different classes that can be re-used such that

- for all columns with `width=6%`, define a class `colWidth6`
- for all columns with `width=8%`, define a class `colWidth8`

There is no need for you to define a separate class for the table itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <style type="text/css">
            .colWidth6{width:6%}
            .colWidth8{width:8%}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="colWidth6">
                <col class="colWidth8">
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell 1</td>
                    <td>Cell 2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. "colgroup" styling td's just Heaven! 

Now what about assigning different widths for tables(almost 30 now)? Just like td, for each "table width" defining class, makes sense?? (dont forget we have already used width class for individual td's). I don't think, we can achieve optimized CSS this way. Tables will used only once within site but bulky CSS is common for site! We may compramising with user experiece by increasing some additional bytes for the sake of good markup??